# Nested controllers in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I`m new with Umbraco so I'd like to know: Is it possible to create nested controllers in Umbraco? Is it possible to have several methods in the Render Controller?

I want the url like this: 
http://www.HOST/dates/[date]/place/[placeId]/entities/[entityId]

Also I had to get data from the database on each level.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do anything you can do with standard ASP.Net MVC; however you probably want to read up on Umbraco's controllers etc. and Route Hijacking here:

- https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Implementation/Controllers/
- https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Implementation/Custom-Routing/
- https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/